# How to get my contract renewed when my supervisor is not happy with my progress as junior developer

Tags: software-industry, work-environment, software-development, developer, junior

After finishing my studies as a computer engineer, I got this job with absolutely no professional experience, and the employer knew that all the projects that I've worked on were just university projects and such. I promised myself that I will focus on this job and actually become a great developer one day. I started learning at work and also come home after 4pm and continue working on the things that I'm going to implement the next day. All the technologies we use at work are new to me and I'd never even heard they existed while I was in the university.

Things started getting complicated after 2 months of getting this job where I started hearing from the senior that is responsible for me that communication with me is hard. It was that he thinks that when he tells me something, I nod and act like I understand but that I actually don't. Some of what he said is true. To be honest, I did do that only when I was really new at the job (like 1 month or so in) because I was insecure about my knowledge and didn't want them to think that I'm stupid, and I took the things that I do not understand as a homework to get to know on my own without their help (and succeeded). He mentioned this two times and I said ok I'm done doing that, I'll start asking more questions and actually listen to the advice I'm getting.

At the moment I do feel like I'm getting way better than before. I implement new features, I can write good readable code, and my solutions work, but I of course ask questions (around maybe 4-5 times a day) in order to better myself and to not make decisions on my own. I actually thought things were finally getting better and that things were finally looking good for me, just to be surprised yesterday that I get called to the teamleader's office where he tells me that I am not doing well at this job and that I do not have the experience he thought I had when he offered me the job, that I do not have the general understanding of their work procedures, hard to communicate with and if these things do not get better he will not be renewing my contract which ends in 2 months.

Now I totally do not agree with him and I told him that and I went to the senior that's responsible for me and asked why the teamleader is saying these things to me, when I clearly do see a big change in my knowledge in the past months. I get the answer from him saying that they see I lack knowledge in the language (typescript), I do not listen to advice, I ask the same question too much, and I was totally in shock because i'm 100% sure this isn't true...

I calmed down and I went to work today, wrote a piece of code we needed for a feature, and went to another senior and asked him to do me a code review. I exactly asked him to check the structure of the code, the use of variable/function names and if the code is good enough for their standards. He said yes the code is good you are getting better.

Now I am totally lost, who do I believe? those two or myself and the guy from today? I totally feel like a failure, like I am not good enough to be a developer, like I wasted the last 4 years in university just to find out I'm not good enough for this branch...

My question to you guys and I do apologize for the long story, is how do I tackle this situation?

What do I do in order to NOT get fired, because it's really bad out there with getting a job as a junior with no experience.

Also, right now I feel like I hate this job and I really want to quit, if it wasn't for the bills I have to pay. What do I do? Do I start seeking jobs now while I'm working and what do I tell these other employers? Do I tell them that I'm working or that i still haven't found a job?

Please advise me and be 100% honest

Again, I'm sorry for writing so much.

Comment: There is an big difference between getting fired and not having your contract renewed so I've adjusted the title to make that clear, feel free to adjust if you feel that's incorrect.

Comment: Well that's not wrong at all. Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible you do ask the same questions or possibly very similar questions repeatedly? Maybe they're things you don't recognise as being the same. You also say you sometimes ask questions to avoid making decisions. Are you sure you shouldn't be making those decisions? Do you ask your questions all at once or separately throughout the day? Do you show that you tried to solve it yourself before asking? Asking questions can be good or bad depending on what and how you ask, so more detail would help us help you.

Comment: You took a contract and the opportunity has ended. That _could_ be because of you, but could be a million other reasons (budget, staff, changing business needs, etc). There is no shame in moving on. Highlight all the things you've learned and how much better you've become in your CV. I think you may find you're more in demand than you think. New folks out of college often know very little about the actual world of work, but you now have some experience, and it seems like you are willing to learn and grow, and to put in the effort to become better. Do not worry and move forward with optimism.

Comment: "What do I do in order to NOT get fired, because it's really bad out there with getting a job as a junior with no experience." - Except you now have experience.  You avoid getting fired by improving, and you improve in the areas, your boss is worried about.  It sounds like you do not communicate well you need to work on that, but I would not take second hand information, take it directly from the source.

Answer (score 3):

> I actually thought things were finally getting better and that things
>   were finally looking good for me, just to be surprised yesterday that
>   i get called to the teamleader's office where he tells me that i am
>   not doing well at this job and that i do not have the experience he
>   thought i had when he offered me the job, that i do not have the
>   general understanding of their work procedures, hard to communicate
>   with and if these things do not get better he will not be renewing my
>   contract which ends in 2 months.
>
> Now i am totally lost, who do i believe? those two or myself and the
>   guy from today?

You can believe anyone you choose to believe. But as far as getting your contract renewed, it's likely that there's only one opinion that matters. It appears that the team leader's opinion is that one.

> My question to you guys and i do apologize for the long story, is how
>   do i tackle this situation?

If you want to salvage this job, talk with the team leader and find out what you should be doing right now. Listen carefully, and try hard to follow his directions. Work hard, improve as best you can.

If you don't want to salvage this job, then update your CV and start your job search while working out your remaining two months.

At the end of two months, you'll know where you stand either way. Be prepared.

These things happen. Sometimes the needs of the position are not a good fit for the accepted candidate. If it ends up not working out, just put it behind you and move on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do agree with you despite hating the situation im put in.

When you say update your CV and start your job search, do i start the job search with keeping this company on my resume or do i remove it? And what do i tell the other emplyers if i kept them on my CV?

Comment: Totally agreeing, but say they choose not to renew my contract, do i keep them on my CV?

Comment: Well, not keeping them on my CV will not create a gap, it is totally okay for someone to finish school and look for jobs for 6 months, the interviewer can be told that nobody decided to hire me yet

Comment: because i really dont know what i would say, they let me go because i couldnt program? that is like saying please dont hire me lol

Comment: I do not want to lie, but i cannot imagine what kind of reaction and interviewer would have when they hear me saying yeah they thought i was bad, so they did not renew my contract

Comment: *when they hear me saying yeah they thought i was bad* there's a difference between being a bad employee (someone who doesn't show up for work, or is destructive, lazy, or abusive - or has other core issues) versus *a bad fit* - someone who isn't quite right for the position and employer. If anything, you sound like you fit into the latter, not the former. No reasonable hiring manager will hold that against you - they will want to concentrate on determining if you'll fit with them, not whether or not you fit with your last employer.

Comment: I want to thank everybody for taking the time to write to me. I will talk with the senior as soon as i get to see him and i will have a discussion with him to determine what EXCACTLY i have to learn in order to keep this job. Meanwhile, i will start applying for jobs again just to be safe. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not doing well at this job and that I do not have the experience he thought I had when he offered me the job, that I do not have the general understanding of their work procedures, hard to communicate with and if these things do not get better he will not be renewing my contract which ends in 2 months.

The teamleader is giving you a heads up. For reasons unknown you will not have your contract renewed. The rest is just made up reasons.

I say this because if they had any actual interest in renewing your contract and there really was serious problems, the teamleader and others would be working with you on positive strategies to get it done. Instead you're getting vagueish threats as a prelude to non renewal.

Comment: You have a point, as i also had the feeling this was true. What do you think i should do now? Fight for this job and actually try to get things better, or just use these 2 months to find another one?

Comment: Both. You should try your best regardless in your own interests. But also job search. Knowing someones agenda is great, it gives you an advantage. But you don't let their agenda dictate yours unless it coincides with what you want

Comment: Does that mean i should be searching jobs and telling potential employees about my situation? or just ignore telling them that i work here

Comment: No need to bad mouth your employer at all... don't do that.

Comment: No, but i will eventually have to explain what happened, not bad mouthing but shouldn't i tell them that there were issues with my current job?

Comment: Why? All I ever do is say I want the job they're offering or I want a change..... Why would you say 'I need a job because they weren't going to renew my contract because of bad performance.'?